# Collect router logs with php

Tags: php, logging, router

I am a newbie in PHP. I just want to know how to how to collect router logs and display it in a webpage? Interface should be written in PHP. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your router supports SSH you can use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to login and get the logs via ssh commands then use it in your PHP application

Here is a snippet that shows how to connect to SSH via phpseclib:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not a good idea to write something like that, because it is important to secure this really well. There are many steps involved (like login to router, get the files to the webserver, have some layout for the webpage, create login, storing files, etc), so it is not just a simple script...
Instead have a look at splunk.com , it might be what you want.